# React-navigation + react-native-web for web project, how to navigate to correct screen using url

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-web

I'm trying to use `react-navigation` and `react-native-web` as described in https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/web-support.html (nothing much.. just says it's possible)

If a user sends a link to his friend `example.com/some/path` I'd like to show him correct screen.

How can I achieve that using react-navigation? Can you read url and render the correct screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it turns out, as of now, react-navigation doesn't even support stack-navigator for web.

So it's not worth pursuing this route.

Comment: Would this still be the case with the new React-Navigation 5.0? (https://reactnavigation.org/next)

Comment: I would check their git  if there's a navigator for natives. I guess you will want to check if their react-navigation/native@next has something like StackNavigator..

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I did exactly that, it seems to be working though with a lot of warnings from underlying `react-native-reanimated`.